# Jquery Accordion from scratch: Markup for accordion & Jquery performance Q

Tags: jquery, html, performance, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Many thanks for any responses.

I'm writing a jquery accordion, but wonder if my markup and jquery are correct or not..(in keeping with semantic html)

my first question is what is the correct semantic html for an accourdion in the context that I'm using it for ([JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Hj4/)).. currently I use an ul... with a li and a div for the content..

second question, can this jquery be improved and is there away of measuring the performance of a specific jQuery script?

[JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Hj4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //store the exact block of html we are working with... the context
    var $context = $("ul#accordion")[0];
    console.log($context);
    //check the context
    $("li a", $context).live("click", function(e){
       //store this due to being used more than once
        var $clicked = $(this);
        //slide anything up thats already open
        $("li div", $context).slideUp(200);
        //test to see if the div is hidden or not..
        //slide down if hidden
        if($clicked.next().is(":hidden")){
            $clicked.next().slideDown(200);
        };
    //prevent default behaviour 
    e.preventDefault();
    });

});​
```

Comment: Both looks fine to me. For your interest you might want to compare with the source example of jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: I would do `$clicked.next(':hidden').slideDown(200);` instead of `if(...)`. Also, since an id has to be unique, `[0]` can be omitted at `$context`. `$clicked` is used only once, so I recommend removing it, and use `$("li div", this)` directly.

Comment: great, I never thought of that way - lost two lines :P ty

Comment: looks nice, only thing I noticed is the `$context` variable. Is usual to add `$` prefix to variables containing jQuery objects, your `$context` contains DOM object. But this really does not matter:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you're using `$(selector, context)` (equal to `$(context).find(selector)`), on only one element, I recommend merging them: `$('ul#accordion li')`
- Use [`$(ancestor).on('event', 'selector', fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `$('ancestor selector').live(fn)`
- Place `e.preventDefault()` on top. Whenever an error occurs in your code, negative side-effects won't occur.
- *My other suggested changes are adressed in the comment on your question.*

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // :first can be omitted, but it's an literal translation
    $("ul#accordion:first li").on("click", "a", function(e) {
        // prevent default behaviour 
        e.preventDefault();

        // slide anything up thats already open
        $("li div", this).slideUp(200);

        // slide down if hidden
        $clicked.next(':hidden').slideDown(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks rob this is the exact type of answer I was looking for, much appreciated.